EF Core 8 dbcontext not loading new data when another app is changing data
I have a Blazor app that accesses data using EF Core. When a separate app edits state on the data, my Blazor app is not getting the data correctly when I reload it.
It fails to load when I try to get the whole set like this:
_context.Line.Where(i => i.id == id)

However what is even more confusing it does work if I were to do this:
_context.Line
        .Where(i => i.id == id).Where(s => s.state != State.Recorded)

The second app changes some items that are of state "New" to state "Recorded"
If I only wanted to display the items that are not recorded, it works fine. Every time I reload the data from the context it knows to get the latest data. But if I try to get the whole set of items (which is what I need), it does not reload the data from DB it just shows the set as it was before, in other words with the sates as they were.
Is there any way i can force my context to get the data from the DB?
Also, why does it do it already when loading only partial data?
For more clarification, it does not work, if exclude items from the query that were not manipulated.
So for example if I were to say this:
_context.Line
        .Where(i => i.id == id)
        .Where(s => s.state != State.Flag)

it would be the same as if I tried getting the whole set.

Maybe read through this. : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0#database-access   I'm not a blazor expert, but I know there are caveats with the IoC scope (or "new it up").

In addition to @GuruStron's answer see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor on using DbContexts on a transactional basis.

This happens because Entity Framework uses tracking mechanism (doc and doc). If data was already fetched by the context and it is tracked then EF will only check if data was added/removed in the database but it will not remap the tracked data (i.e. if some columns were altered in the database)/
There are multiple options here (depending on the use case):

Disable change tracking either globally or on per request basis with AsNoTracking.
Clear change tracker manually with context.ChangeTracker.Clear(); call
Recreate the context (do not forget to dispose the old one) for example via DbContext factory

Also please see: How does caching work in Entity Framework?

That only explains half the situation. Why would it give me the correct result when i request partial data?

@zawisza because it operates on the dataset which is returned by the query. It will query the database but it will not remap the data. If you had 3 items which are New then one of them became Recorded - the second query will return only 2 items which you will get (if there are other columns which were updated then as far as I understand you will not observe the change, but have not checked that). P.S. possibly using concurrency token can affect things too - but have not experimented with it.

"Why would it give me the correct result when i request partial data" if you mean projection via Select, these always go to the database, not the tracking cache. Generally for read operations you should aim to use projections wherever possible. When updating fetch entities, but be sure that the lifetime scope of the DbContext isn't longer than needed. (not so much an issue with web apps but can be more of an issue with Blazor) Ideally the DbContext should live to serve just the Update operation.
